# Ubuntu 14.04-Windows 10 dual boot makes windows hang

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

I have a dual boot Ubuntu 14.04<>Windows 10 system. It has two SSD-drives, 256 GB for Windows and 128 GB for Ubuntu and one 1 TB HDD for data. 
Ubuntu works without any problems, Windows 10, however, often hangs for minute long periods something that is very annoying. 
If I physically remove the Ubuntu SSD Windows seems to be ok, also if I via BIOS, skipping GRUB, boot directly into Windows the problem seems to disappear.
I would like to understand what causes the problem and what I can do about it.
Thanks in advance for any tip.
H

PS The upside is that I now prefer working with Linux.

Comment: Interesting… Since everything okay without grub, it looks to me like, perhaps, Win10  expects something to be uninitialized during the boot, but grub does it. Hard to say, in general looks something like that. I'd ask at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) — probably there would be more peoples aware of Win10 internals. Perhaps is there logs of some kind? I'm really curious.

Comment: This may well be a question best asked elsewhere; but before you go, or post elsewhere, it's imperative that you determine your boot mode -- BIOS/CSM/legacy or EFI/UEFI. This might differ between Windows and Linux (and if it does, that could even be part of the problem). See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootmode.html) for detailed instructions for both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Can't write comments to your main question due to low reputation points. I wanted to tell you that (or at least it used to be) windows will boot fine when it sees its partition as "active".

Let's say you're going to install Windows: First you boot onto your disk and this will report an error about "missing operating system". Perfect! at this point the disk/partition is marked as Active. Now you can reboot and continue installing Windows. Windows bootloader will be installed on that disk.

Linux does not care. You can install its bootloader on a old floppy if you wish..

But this is probably a cause why your Windows have difficulties booting when another disk is inserted.

Comment: What's «active disk»? The first time I hear that. Anyway, that's not look like the case because then probably Win10 would rather have troubles with booting up, than hangs for running.

Comment: It's just a way Windows wants to be installed. First you boot to the disk making it active and then you install Windows. Ever happened to see Windows installed on a D:\ .. E:\ and so on.. drive?? Well.. that's why ;) Windows must be installed on C:\  It's not just about the driver letter rather a way for Windows to identifies its disk. But this happened with version previous than Windows Vista.. (not sure whether fixed or not, still, this is how to install Windows)   hangs or troubles.. it anyway boots fine when linux disk is removed.. I believe if you'd install Windows like this you'd resolve

Comment: Before I came to GNU/Linux, I reinstalled Windows many times. The «drive C» is always the one where the system is installed, with disregard to its physical location. For example I had two WindowsXP on one drive *(i.e. two partitions)*, and when I was booting to any, it always did show it's system drive as «C», and the other one as «D». I've never seen that Windows showed it's system drive as «D», or whatever.

Comment: good for you mate! I worked with customers more than I should and this windows thing was often there.. but again, it doesn't happen often (also because you'd reinstall windows on the same disk you used before so technically you already boot up on an active disk) but it happened to me at the very beginning of my "career" and I discovered this.. I mean.. what I say is a good hint, not saying with this you 100% solve, but I too had linux and windows and discovered strange behaviours from windows when changing boot disk ( at the end I left LILO doing the boot for windows )

Comment: The concept of an "active partition" is an MBR concept that does not apply to GPT disks. As this is a Windows 10 system, the odds are high that it boots in EFI mode using GPT disks, so this concept may not apply. user37342: ***DO NOT*** try to set the "active" or "boot" flag on any of your partitions until you figure this out! The "boot flag" on a GPT disk, in GParted and `parted`, means something entirely different, and setting it on a Windows partition will just create new problems!